# Matching text in UITextField to a list in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

In my app I have a text box, a table view, and a database. I want to make it so that when I click on the text box and write something in it, my table view will display the list of words similar or identical to the word or words I have entered into the text field. Please, can anyone provide me a suitable idea for implementing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you edit text field, the delegate method textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: gets called. Use this to fetch records from database and reload the tableview.

See similar post [here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-uisearchdisplaycontroller-with-nspredicate/) and apple's sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: pleaase give me a demo or sample cdoe if u have please